# Eigenvalue matrix and Eigenvector matrix for $A+2I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A = U \Lambda U^{-1}$$ Where $U^{-1}$ is inverse of $U$

Then, I want to find eigenvalue matrix and eigenvector matrix for $A+2I$

It seems reasonable to guess that eigenvalue matrix for $A+2I$ is $\Lambda +2I$ and that the eigenvectors remain the same.

What is the proof behind this?

Comment: $UU^*=I$ and $A+2I= U\Lambda U^* + 2UU^* = U(\Lambda+2I)U^*$. However, I'm not sure that *eigenvalue matrix* is a legitimate term, and $A=U\Lambda U^*$ is known as the *eigendecomposition* of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to note that
$$
U(\Lambda + 2I)U^{-1} = U\Lambda U^{-1} + 2UU^{-1} = A + 2I
$$
Since $\Lambda$ was a diagonal matrix, $\Lambda + 2I$ is also diagonal.  So, the transformation $U$ diagonalizes $A + 2I$ to yield the diagonal matrix $\Lambda + 2I$.  So, $A + 2I$ has an eigendecomposition with "eigenvalue matrix" $\Lambda + 2I$ and "eigenvector matrix" $U$.